# Multiple row filter and Calculate percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, pivot, percentage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c81rS.png)I am new to SQL. I am working on a database where I need to filter and then calculate percentage. Below is the sample table.
Steps to follow:

- First filter Column Nature which has only Create, Review and Coordinate.
- Group by Column, Team, TeamTeam, Client and sum the hours.
- Then calculate the % of Creat, Review and Coordinate based on above group.
- Final I need output columns Team, TeamTeam, Client, %Create, %Review and %Coordinate.

Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhPPO.png)

Comment: Given your sample data, what should the result table look like?

Comment: Team TeamTeam Client Coordinate Create Review Sum_Hours Review % Coordinate % Create %
Team 1 Team BB ABC1 3 1  9 0% 33% 11%
Team 1 Team CC ABC1   2 2 100% 0% 0%
Team 1 Team DD ABC1    4 0% 0% 0%
Team 2 Team BB ABC2   7 27 26% 0% 0%
Team 2 Team CC ABC2  6  16 0% 0% 38%
Team 2 Team DD ABC2 8   8 0% 100% 0%
Team 3 Team BB ABC3 19 17 13 64 20% 30% 27%
Team 3 Team CC ABC3 14  18 32 56% 44% 0%
Team 3 Team DD ABC3  12  28 0% 0% 43%

Comment: I have added output image in the main query. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with a `where` clause, and then use `group by` and `sum`. To compute the percentages, a straight-forward method is `avg()` and conditional aggregation.

```
select team, client, sum(hours) sum_hours,
    avg(case when nature = 'create'     then 100.0 else 0 end) percent_create,
    avg(case when nature = 'review'     then 100.0 else 0 end) percent_review,
    avg(case when nature = 'coordinate' then 100.0 else 0 end) percent_coordinate
from mytable
where nature in ('create', 'review', 'coordinate')
group by team, client
```

Comment: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric. I am getting this error for the sum I am trying to perform. How to change the data type? I am using "sum(cast([Hours]as decimal)) as Sum_Hours,

Comment: I also tried "SUM(CAST([Hours] AS numeric)) as sum_hours" not working

Comment: Nicely done!  I like the way the group percentages are calculated.  Cool

Comment: @Rock use try_convert(numeric(12), [hours]) it will return null if the column contains something which won't convert